# How do I force a download PHP?

Tags: php, download

This script keeps returning the "else" response.  Why does my condition keep failing:

```
<?php

    $fileName = $_GET['far_sighted_michael_pitluk.mp3'];
    $fileDisplayName = "Far-Sighted";

    // Fetch the file info.
    $filePath = 'http://michaelpitluk.com/audio/far_sighted_michael_pitluk.mp3';

    if(file_exists($filePath)) {
        $fileName = basename($filePath);
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);

        // Output headers.
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Content-Type: application/stream");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileDisplayName);

        // Output file.
        readfile ($filePath);                   
        exit();
    }
    else {
        die('The provided file path is not valid.');
    }
?>
```

I don't understand what's wrong with the path.

Comment: is the mp3 on your server?

Comment: `$_GET['far_sighted_michael_pitluk.mp3'];` are you sure that param is named that way? That's weird.

Comment: @Dagon yes. [Far-sighted](http://michaelpitluk.com/audio/far_sighted_michael_pitluk.mp3).

Comment: then use the local file path

Comment: @Dagon i used "..audio/far_sided_michael_pitluk.mp3" and that worked insofar as the browser started downloading something, but it didn't end up being an mp3. my comp didn't know how to read it. do you know why?

Comment: thy the mp3 Content type `Content-Type: audio/mpeg`

Comment: @Dagon actually bansi pointed out that i needed .mp3 in my fileDisplayName variable.  it works now. thanks for the help. the local path is what i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `$filePath` starts with `http://` you may require to enable `allow_url_fopen`. [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

Try

```
ini_set("allow-url-fopen", true);
// Fetch the file info.
$filePath = 'http://michaelpitluk.com/audio/far_sighted_michael_pitluk.mp3';
```

Edit:
Try this:

```
<?php

    $fileName = $_GET['far_sighted_michael_pitluk.mp3'];
    $fileDisplayName = "Far-Sighted.mp3";

    // Fetch the file info.
    $filePath = '../audio/far_sighted_michael_pitluk.mp3';

    if(file_exists($filePath)) {
        $fileName = basename($filePath);
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);

        // Output headers.
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileDisplayName);

        // Output file.
        readfile ($filePath);                   
        exit();
    }
    else {
        die('The provided file path is not valid.');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the condition still failed with this. Although, I don't understand why.  Seems like it should work, any thoughts?

Comment: @MichaelPitluk This will only work if the file is accessible as `URL` from your server. From your previous post it looks like the file is on your server and you may not need this.

Comment: that's it! awesome! could you edit your answer to include that? so i can select it as the answer?  i had to just use the local path and change the fileDisplayName

Comment: @MichaelPitluk Full code. I have also changed the `Content type` to work on all browsers, and `$fileDisplayName`

Comment: works perfect, thanks! that's the first real php script i've ever ran, so double thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

fileexist() function takes a path to your file on your host , not a full URL 
Try This

```
$filePath = 'audio/far_sighted_michael_pitluk.mp3';
```

Comment: Worked when I used "..audio/far_sighted_michael_pitluk.mp3" Thanks!

Comment: Can you think of any reason why the browser starts to download, but the file is not an .mp3? My mac just tells me that it's a document and when I open it it says the app can't be found.

Comment: @MichaelPitluk `$fileDisplayName = "Far-Sighted";` should be `$fileDisplayName = "Far-Sighted.mp3";`

Comment: @MichaelPitluk AFAIK Browser starts to download if it doesn't know how to deal with the coming data or the content type is set to allow download